# Uniformly approximating a function and its derivative using polynomials

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

I'm struggling either proving or disproving the following statement:

> Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact, and $S = \mathrm{span}\{p_k, k = 0, 1, \ldots\}$, where $p_k$'s are polynomials over $K$. If $S$ is dense in $C^1(K)$ with respect to sup-norm, then for any $f\in C^1(K)$, there exists $\{g_n\} \subset S$ such that $g_n$ uniformly approximates $f$ with $f'$ uniformly approximated by $g_n'$.

This statement seems to be true, although $S$ is only a subset of all polynomials over $K$. If the statement appears false, is there any prior assumption that makes it true? Any reference or direct answer would greatly help me.

Comment: Is $C(K)$ supposed to be $\mathrm C^1(K)$?  Otherwise, it's not even clear what $f'$ means.  (Also, where does this come from?  It looks like a homework question.)

Comment: @LSpice Yes. It should be $C^1(K)$. I've changed the original post. It's actually an intermediate step in a theorem that I would like to prove in my research work. I tried to look up real-analysis references. But I didn't find anything useful...

Comment: Let's start with the case in which $K$ is an interval $[a,b]$.  If $h$ is a polynomial that $\varepsilon$-approximates $f'$, then $H(x):=f(a)+\int_a^x h(z)\,\mathrm{d}z$ is a polynomial that $\delta$-approximates $f$, where $\delta:=\varepsilon |b-a|$.

Comment: @Algernon Thanks for the answer here. I'm more interested in the case where $S$ is a subset of all polynomials. The tricky part in your comment is that $\int_a^x h(z)dz$ does not necessarily lie in $S$.

Comment: Oooh, I see.  Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Still, what I said reduces the problem to the case where $f$ is itself a polynomial.

Comment: An equivalent reformulation: if the span of $\{p_k\}$ is dense in $C(K)$, is the span of $\{p_k’\}$ also dense?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Thanks so much for the straightforward counter-example here. But I'm a bit slow on the reformulation here. How can we argue that if $\{\p_k'}$ is also dense, then we can find $g_k$ such that $g_k\to f$ and $g'_k\to f'$ at the same time?

Comment: Hm, right! It seems that this works only if constants are in the span (which I somehow implicitly assumed...). Otherwise that would be true only if we work in the space of functions vanishing at a certain point.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov It’s fair to assume that $S$ consists of constants. What I wonder here is even we assume the span of $\{p_k’\}$ is dense, there is still no guarantee on existence of $g_k$, is there? Or am I missing anything straightforward?

Comment: Well, OK, you should have all functions which are constant on each segment in $K$. In this case, you may proceed as in  @Algernon’s comment, approximating $f’$ by the derivatives, and then correcting the approximation of $f$ by those constants.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I got what you meant. I forgot we can approximate $f’$ if we assume span of $\{p_k’\}$ is also dense. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The span of $\{x^{2k}\colon k=0,1,2,\dots\}$ is dense in $C([0,1])$. But all their derivatives vanish at $0$.

Comment: To see the density:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2733385/34287

Comment: @StevenGubkin, or just because it's an algebra that separates points!

Comment: @LSpice Sure, sure just recording an easy reference for anyone who doesn't know this stuff.

Comment: So you may create a separate question, if  you wish many people ro see it.

Answer (score 3):

[*Update:* As Pietro Majer pointed out in the comments, the following does not answer the OP's question, but a variant in which $S=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots\}$ instead of $S=\operatorname{span}(\{p_1,p_2,\ldots\})$.]

Not necessarily.

For simplicity, let $K=[0,1]$.
Let $T_0=\{u_1,u_2,\ldots\}$ be a countable dense set in $C(K)$ whose elements are differentiable, say the set of polynomials with rational coefficients.  For each $n$, let
\begin{align*}
   v_n(x) &:= u_n + \frac{1}{n}\sin(\beta(n)x) \;.
\end{align*}
for some function $\beta:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ that grows rapidly to $\infty$.
Note that

- $T_1:=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots\}$ is still a countable dense set in $C(K)$;
- Each $v_n$ is differentiable;
- Assuming $\beta$ grows fast enough, $\|v'_n\|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Finally, for each $n$, let $p_n$ be a polynomial such that $\|p_n-v_n\|<2^{-n}$ and $\|p'_n-v'_n\|<2^{-n}$.  Let $S:=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots\}$.

Now, clearly $S$ is dense in $C(K)$, but $S':=\{p'_1,p'_2,\ldots\}$ cannot be dense in $C(K)$ because $\|p'_n\|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Note that  $S$ is the *span* of the $p_k$, so there are many other converging sequences $g_n$ in $S$ (for instance $S$ could be the whole ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$, in which case the OP statement is true),  so it seems more complicated (I also think it's not true, for similar reasons)

Comment: You are right, I missed the fact that $S$ is supposed to be the span of $p_1,p_2,\ldots$.

Answer (score 3):

*Any prior assumption that makes it true*. A   simple case where your statement is true is the case of   an interval $K\subset\mathbb{R}_+ $, and $(p_k)_{k\ge0}$ are monomials, $p_k(x)=x^{n_k}$, of degrees $0=n_0<n_1<\dots$. For in this case,   by the [Müntz-Szász Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem),  the  $(p_k)_{k\ge0}$ span a dense subspace in $C^0(I)$, if and only if their derivatives $(p'_k)_{k\ge0}$ do (this of course because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n_k}=+\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n_k-1}=+\infty$).
If by the assumption $S$ is uniformly dense in $C^1(I)$, it is also uniformly dense in $C^0(I)$, therefore the span of the $(p'_k)_{k\ge0}$ is also uniformly dense in $C^0(I)$. Hence, for any $f\in C^1(K)$ there is a sequence $g_n\in S$ such that $g_n'$ converges uniformly to $f'$; since $S$ contains the constants, we can assume $g_n$ converges to $g$ at least on a pont of $K$, but then also $g_n$ converges uniformly to $f $ by the theorem of limit under the sign of derivative.

Comment: Note I assumed $0\notin K$, as it is needed to apply the Muntz-Szász Theorem. If $0\in K$, the  trivial exceptions  can be ruled out e.g. assuming  $ n_0=0$ and $n_1=1 $ .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know of M\"{u}ntz-Szasz theorem. May I ask if there are any extensions on the cases where $p_k$'s are not monomials? The cases that I'm mostly interested in are (1) $p_k = a^k b$ for some fixed polynomials $a$ and $b$ (2) $p_k$'s are vector-valued polynomials. But these cases seem to be more complicated and less-addressed in the literature of polynomial approximation.

Comment: I don't know of the extensions to polynomials, but I guess there are some. An  obvious extension is the case of  polynomials  $p_k$ that  maybe are not monomials but whose span coincides with a span of monomials $x^{n_k}$ satisfying MS hypothesis. Or also, polynomials $p_k=L(x^{n_k})$ for $L$ an invertible operator on $C^0(K)$